# What is the default link function for the multinom family in mgcv?

Tags: mgcv

I've looked for this information but haven't been able to find it. I assume it's a logit link but I'm not sure.

Comment: `?multinom` has the mathematical form of the transformation. For binary categories, it is the same as a logistic regression i.e. logit link

Comment: Thanks for your response - so would it still be logit if there are more than two categories of the response?

Comment: From what I'm understanding, it would not be a logit per se, but an extension of it.

Comment: I'm wondering how to back-transform the estimates to the linear scale? Even looking at the model in R, the link is listed as "NULL"

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm providing a solution in case anyone else is struggling to figure out how to put predictions on the response scale for a multinomial regression. There is a great starting point here: https://fromthebottomoftheheap.net/2018/12/10/confidence-intervals-for-glms/ (thank you Gavin Simpson!)

Basically if you do
`fam<-family(multinomial_model)$linfo[[1]]`
This gets you the information for the link for your model - it is a bit different from the example in hyperlink above, since this information is in a list format for multinomial models. I've selected the first element (i.e. the link for comparison of one level of factor to reference level), but as far as I'm aware, these should be identical for the comparison of other levels of the response to the reference level. You can then access link (and inverse link) information with

`fam$linkfun`
`fam$linkinv`
(*note: not `fam$linkfun()` or `fam$linkinv()`)

and plug these into your equations